# Mouse - System settings (GUI) changes not taking effect on Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma Enviroment

Tags: mouse, system-settings

Lenovo ideapad 320.

I would prefer to fix this issue via the GUI but a fix from terminal would also be acceptable.

```
xinput --list --short
```

I have Logitech USB Receiver

```
xinput --set-prop "Logitech USB Receiver" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5

Warning: There are multiple devices matching 'Logitech USB Receiver'.
To ensure the correct one is selected, please use the device ID, or prefix the
device name with 'pointer:' or 'keyboard:' as appropriate.
```

What would be the correct code with "id9"? Or GUI fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

Make sure you do it in the following order or you will be left with no input software - basically you need to apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev package then apt-get remove the xserver-xorg-input-libinput package. Restart and you will have sensitivity and acceleration functionality again.

If touchpad is not working afterwords:

sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

and reboot.

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=153890